# Given Directed Graph G(V,E) with red/black vertices, v is good if there's a path from v to a black vertex

Tags: algorithms

**Given** Directed Graph G(V,E) with red/black vertices, v is "good" if there's a path from v to a black vertex. **in linear time**.

**Question:** Find all the good vertices in the graph

I've come up with an algorithm which almost works.

1. Run SCC on G.
2. Sort topologically.
3. Run from the last SCC till the first SCC.
4. If we find a black node, return all the previous SCCs nodes and the current SCC's nodes (because all the nodes are reachable in the SCC).

This algorithm fails because there may be SCC's which are not connected to the SCC that we found the black node. How can I fix the algorithm to work?

Comment: Wouldn't flood fill on the dual graph just work? Or I'm understanding the problem wrong?

Comment: Your don't state that your graph acyclic. How can you do topological sort?

Comment: @fade2black After I run SCC algorithm the graph becomes DAG as far as I remember.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed that part.

Comment: Do you search for a path from the vertex $v$ to some (at least one) black vertex?

Comment: @fade2black So I will need to run BFS/DFS on every vertex V. it won't be linear. but O(V(V+E)).

Comment: @fade2black What if I run on all the edges and find the cross edges. Then, After finding a black vertex, I will return all the vertices in the SCC's that are connected with the cross edges I marked? Cross edges I believe can be found in linear time because we just need to check all the edges of the graph with is O(E). They're found by checking that they're not tree edges, not back edges, and not forward edges, we can classify that by changing a bit the DFS algorithm in the SCC run for example. What do you think?

Comment: If there is an edge from a $SCC_i$ to another $SCC_j$ and there is a black node in the $SCC_j$ all nodes in $SCC_i$ are good. If you mean by cross-edges the edges between SCCs then I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Lets consider the case where you need to be $O(V+E)$. As someone in the comments mentioned, the way I thought about it was reversing the edges, as described below:

1. Reverse all edges
2. For every unvisited black vertex, perform a BFS/DFS on all unvisited nodes, marking them visited as you search.
3. All visited nodes are good.

It is trivial to see that if and only if a node is marked visited, it can reach a black vertex in the original graph. The forward direction is simple, if a node is visited, then there is a direct path to a black vertex. The other direction is also true, if there is a path from a node to a black vertex in the original graph, that that node would clearly have been visited by one of the searches.

Now, let's say you want to stick with the SCC strategy. We first find all SCC's in $O(V+E)$ time. Then, for each SCC we condense it to a single node and color it black if it contained a black node and red otherwise. All edges into and out of the each SCC will now lead into and out of the new corresponding condensed node. Now we can just perform the same algorithm as above on the new graph with no SCCs! For every node, mark it as good iff its corresponding SCC was visited.